# Android user permissions

Tags: android

I am new to android development and I am making a tic tac toe game for a project at the university.

I know it is a simple game, but I need to add a permission to it so I can show that android has some kind of security.

I was thinking about the thing where the screen doesn't automatically locks, WAKE_LOCK or something like that.

How to implement this ? Is there a way besides the one where you add the code to your xml file ?

I mean something that has to do with `<user-permissions.... />` in manifest so a pop-up with accept can appear to the user ?

Is it enough to add that line to the manifest file or coding is required ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is enough

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Once you request permission in the manifest file, you can then use it within your application as per the dev guide here:-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html